# How to start an activity from application in one device to the application in another device

Tags: android, p2p, android-wifi, android-wireless

i have a scenario like this:

I am developing an android peer to peer application (using android.net.wifi.p2p) and my application detects another android devices in range and connects to those devices. And should  invoke an activity of the same app(my application installed on that device). I know how to start an activity using intents but this time i need to start an activity in another device from my device.

Please guide me through the correct procedure to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to know the basic steps to detect application installed on the other phone and invoke it (assuming both devices are connected thought wifi).

Comment: Would Androids sandboxing even allow this?

Comment: may be i should put it like this my application will send some data to send from my phone to another phone and my application installed on another phone should receive it and show it to the user

Comment: Are you able to have your application running on both devices at all times? I'd have thought that if a user wanted to participate in some sort of mobile P2P activity they would be okay with this running in the background at all times. (Remote activation of an application sounds like it should be disallowed, as @CommonsWare points out).

Comment: yes a service runs all the time on both devices. When the message is sent by the 1st device the service in the second device should receive it and invoke the activity in the application. That's what i want but i don't know how would my service knows whether a message or data is received. And thanks for your reply.

Comment: As per @AdamKing's advice - have you looked at whether the default firewall configuration on an Android device will permit a communication between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know the basic steps to detect application installed on the other phone and invoke it (assuming both devices are connected thought wifi).

There is nothing built into Android for this, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Comment: But can you say me how [Camera Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.busywww.cameraremote) achieve this?

Comment: @Ramswaroop: What that app does is not what the person asking the question was seeking.